# Can Delphi XE4 support iOS 4.x?

Tags: ios, delphi, ios4, delphi-xe4

Looking at the official "supported" iOS versions, I believe 5.x and 6.x are supported. I know it is a long shot, but is there any way to get iOS 4.x support?

Comment: Offtopic side question: I can see title has been altered, so Delphi is not part of it. Why not also remove "iOS" then? What rationale is there behind removing "Delphi" and not "iOS"? Just curious why removing "Delphi" makes the title better for people skimming new questions...

Comment: Older devices are definitly not supported. In fact, you see quite a lot of applications on the Apple AppStore that need iOS5 or even 6 as a minimum. And by the way, even the iPhone 3GS from 2009 runs iOS6 so I guess Embarcadero does not worry about that. However, it's still strange because as far as I can see, the current XCode version can still go back to iOS 4.3

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful I think the reason is that it is slightly harder to upgrade iOS 4.x (requires PC/Mac/Wifi if I recall) than iOs 5/6 which will alow download over mobile internet. (I have never used iPhone as a user, så what I just stated is just info I picked up during passing) - thus some people still on iOS 4.x (e.g. with an IPhone4) even though they could upgrade for no cost

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for certain, but I would guess that it is not likely, or they would probably have done it in the initial release.  Now they are moving on and focusing on Android, so iOS is not the focus right now, at least as far as supporting older versions is concerned.

Comment: I think you are correct. It is a pitty that iOS 4.3 is not supported, but I guess it may be because the FMX framework need something in iOS5 (I am purely guessing though)

Comment: Really, that is not so bad. Because it makes live easier. Devices that are that old would not be fun to watch running an FMX-App. Seriously!