# Using Delphi for ios apps on iphone 4

Tags: ios, delphi, iphone-4

If I have Delphi Seattle with mobile addon and upgrade subscription is there any way I can support Iphone 4 if a customer requests it? Possible as a separate app download?

And if not, would this be a limitation in xcode 6.4 / xcode 7 or in Delphi?

Comment: It's not about the iphone, it's about the iOS version.  If it's still running iOS4, perhaps not, but if at least iOS 5.x+ then likely yes.  iphone4 supports up to iOS7, afaik.  see : http://stackoverflow.com/q/18090790/327083  also http://stackoverflow.com/q/26758808/327083  Two years ago iOS4x was less than 1% of all iOS installations in use.  As a fraction of iPhone4 users I'm not sure what that equates to, but most users seem to have at least upgraded their OS once or twice by now.

Comment: If iOS7 works with IPhone4 and I can use Delphi Seattle for it without running in too much freaky problems with xcode, app submission etc. I am happy. (Upvoted comment)